# What is the point of using this derived PID controller?

Tags: algorithms, control-systems, pid

Previously, I answer for [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/85388/conceptual-doubt-about-pid-algorithm-in-plc) PID controller that I want to understand completly.

This is used for control the opening $U_n$ of a valve let gas pass and reach a certain pressure (SetPoint).

There is current error, and Tsample and 2 Tsample before. Aditionally, there is a variable that store the current change in the error respect the last , and the same Tsample before. Finally a variable that store the variation of the change of the error.

$$e_{n-2}=e_{n-1}$$
$$e_{n-1}=e_n$$
$$e_n=SetPoint-ProcessValue$$

$$P_n=e_n-e_{n-1}$$
$$P_{n-1}=e_{n-1}-e_{n-2}$$

$$Q_{n}=P_n-P_{n-1}=(e_n-e_{n-1})-(e_{n-1}-e_{n-2})$$

And the calculation of control signal, where $dP_n$ is the proportional part, $dI_n$ is the integral part, $dD_n$ is derivative part, $K_p$ is global gain, $R_p$ is proportional gain, $T_i$ integral time, $T_d$ derivative time, and $dU_n$ is the PID output:

$$dP_n=R_p*P_n$$
$$dI_n=T_i*e_n$$
$$dD_{n-1}=dD_{n}$$
$$dD_n=(Q_{n}*T_d+dD_{n-1})/2$$
$$dU_n=K_p*(dP_n+dI_n+dD_n)$$

After that, it calculate the direction of the correction, where PC (positive correction) is a variable with TRUE value if $dU_n>0$ and FALSE value if $dU_n<0$  and NC (negative correction) is TRUE if $dU_n<0$ and FALSE if $dU_n>0$.

If **PC**=TRUE then $U_n$=$U_{n-1}$**+**$dU_n$

If **NC**=TRUE then $U_n$=$U_{n-1}$**-**$dU_n$

In the post whose link I attached at the beginning of the query, Tim Wescott answered me that the step where
$$U_n=U_{n−1}±dU_n$$
is a numerical integration.

He said that this is an ordinary PID controller, with a numerical derivative of every step.

What is the point of using this **derived** PID controller?

Comment: In your original question, the if-then clauses are different -- there they depend on some (presumably preset) variable **PC**.  Here, they depend on the sign of $dU_n$.  This is a significant difference.  Please clarify!

Comment: @TimWescott I just edited, please I await your response. From already thank you very much.